# Retrieving dropped triggers in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, database-trigger

Is there any solution or trick to retrieve dropped triggers in oracle? I searched and found some solutions for retrieving tables but there was no solution for the other things.

Comment: No "solution" or "trick" - you'll just need to re-add the trigger.  Q: How did you drop it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured exp or expdp for your schema then you can get it from the exported dump, otherwise re-create it.